# Проблемы многопоточности в Keras

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

Используя Threading и Keras я пытался сделать распознавание элементов на картинке и наткнулся на проблему.

> ValueError: The name "conv2d_1" is used 2 times in the model. All layer names should be unique.

Слышал, что это типичная проблема Keras в мультипотоках, но как решить - неясно.
Кто-то меняет названия моделей, ещё что-то, но я не могу применить их решения, ибо не пойму куда вставить.

Мой код:

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
import os

execution_path = os.getcwd()
percent = 45
detector = ObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
detector.setModelPath( os.path.join(execution_path , "yolo.h5"))
detector.loadModel()
detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=os.path.join(execution_path , "image.jpg"), output_image_path=os.path.join(execution_path , "image3new.jpg"), minimum_percentage_probability=45)

for eachObject in detections:
    print(eachObject["name"] , " : ", eachObject["percentage_probability"], " : ", eachObject["box_points"] )
    print("--------------------------------")
```

Именно этот код запускается в нескольких потоках.

Добавлю лишь, что имена файлов при обработке каждый раз новые, здесь это **не указано**.

К слову, ещё одна ошибка была решена командой `K.clear_session()` перед строками, начинающимися с `detector`.

Код вызывающий поток с функцией:

```py
def execute(b):
    if 'photo_url' in b :
    #try:
        print('debug1')
        photo_url__ = b.get('photo_url')
        #detection(photo_url__)
        global p
        p = threading.Thread(target=detection, args=(photo_url__,user__id))
        p.start()
```

Код функции `detection()`:

```py
    percent = 45
    execution_path = os.getcwd()
    K.clear_session()
    detector = ObjectDetection()
    detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
    detector.setModelPath( os.path.join(execution_path , "yolo.h5"))
    detector.loadModel()
    #detections = 
    detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=os.path.join(execution_path , 
    'image3.jpg'), output_image_path=os.path.join(execution_path , 
    "image3new.jpg"), minimum_percentage_probability=45)
    img = urllib.request.urlopen(image_url).read()
    out = open('img' + str(w) + ".jpg", "wb")
    out.write(img)
    out.close
    name = 'img' + str(w) + '_new.jpg'
    print(os.path.join(execution_path , 'img' + str(w) + '.jpg'))
    detections = 
    detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=os.path.join(execution_path , 
    'img' + str(w) + '.jpg'), output_image_path=os.path.join(execution_path , 
    'img'  + str(w) + '_new.jpg'), minimum_percentage_probability=30)
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе ту часть кода где вы используюте многопоточность

Answer (score 4):

Я думаю проблема в том, что вы в каждой нитке (`thread`) создаете новый объект - `detector`.

Попробуйте использовать один глобальный `detector`:

```
execution_path = os.getcwd()
percent = 45
detector = ObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
detector.setModelPath(r'C:\work\ML\.data\misc\yolo.h5')
detector.loadModel()

def detect_objects(input_image, output_image_path, 
                   detector=detector, **kwargs):
    r = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image,
                                        output_image_path,
                                        **kwargs)
    return r
```

и далее использовать функцию `detect_objects()`.